# Posting 2 forms on 1 page with Python (Webscraping)

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to build a webscraper for a client of mine that will get the current price as shown on [www.wozwaardeloket.nl](http://www.wozwaardeloket.nl). In the first part I am posting the accept data form and making the page accept the 'cookie alert'.

In the second request I want to post the value of the 'Streetname + Number + City' to second post on the same page. I am a little unexperienced yet with Python so maybe someone could tell me what I am doing wrong?

> import requests
>
> url = 'https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/' eerste_form = {'accept':
> 'true', 'akkoord': 'Verder'} nieuw_keywoord = {'searchInput': name,
> 'searchVal' : "Watermolen 21 Edam" }
>
> x = requests.post(url, data = eerste_form) r = requests.post(x, data =
> nieuw_keywoord)
> #print the response text (the content of the requested file):
>
> print(x.text)

I am trying to make another post requests but apparently it does not work like that, been trying to search the internet but for so far no good results that explain it simple.

Comment: you can try Selenium Webdriver

Comment: The thing is that it should be run from a webhosting / domainonline, So it's not possible to work with Selenium Webdriver if I am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request directly to their API:

https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/api/geocoder/v3/suggest?query=Watermolen%2021%20Edam

Try this URL in your browser and see if it has the data you need.
Then do it this way to get the JSON data in your code.

```
data = request.get(url).json()
```